# Why does <?=?> work on one computer but not another?

Tags: php, php-shorttags

When I write

```
<?=?>
```

in my PC it's not working,but it's work in another PC !!! why ??? :( 
for example :

```
<?php
$courses = CourseManager::findAll();
?>
<h3>Course List</h3>
<table>
    <tr><th>Name</th></tr>
 <?php   foreach ($courses as $c){
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$c->getName()?></td></tr>
  <?php } ?>

</table>
```

or this, it's too simple no ? :)

```
<?= expression ?>
```

This is a shortcut for

```
<? echo expression ?>
```

or

```
<?php
$i ="test";
?>

<h1><?=$i?></h1>
```

Thanks for your advice :)

Comment: Stupid question, but is the same version of php running on both machines?

Comment: Is PHP even installed on the second machine?

Comment: Hi Mike, not a mock, I was saying that I might be asking a silly question

Comment: Note that it's recommended not to use short tags: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have the short tags enabled.

To enable them look for `short_open_tag`s in `php.ini`. Change it to "On" and restart Apache.

Comment: This is not recommended. Get in the habit of using `<?php`. If you migrate to a system where you do not the option to turn short tags on, your code will not work.

Answer (score 6):

PHP's [short_open_tag](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) options isn't the same on different servers. If possible avoid to use these type of opening tags.

If you want to be sure short open tags are available, set it yourself with [ini_set](http://hu.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php).

Answer (score 0):

Check `short_open_tag` in `php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

Because these shortcuts can be turned off in the php.ini. [The option is called `short_open_tags`.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)

Answer (score 0):

See this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php